# AP Calculus BC - Derivative of inverse problem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

Let $g(x)$ be the inverse of the function $f(x)$. Given the following values on the table below, at which value $x=a$ will $g'(a)=1/6$? (No calculator allowed)

```
x     -1   2   4   6   7
f(x)   3   5  -2   8  -6
f'(x)  2   6   9   7   5
```

I'm confused with derivatives of inverses and have no idea proceed with this problem. A step-by-step explanation would be super awesome! Thank you.

Comment: Hint:  $g\circ f (x)=x\implies g'(f(x))f'(x)=1\implies g'(f(x))=\frac 1{f'(x)}$ .  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

By the inverse function theorem, if the function f is differentiable, the inverse $g(x)$ is differentiable as long as $f'(x) \neq 0$, and if we set $y=f(x)$, $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{dy/dx}$.

So, in this case, we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{g'(a)}=\frac{1}{1/6}=6$. According to the chart, at $x=2$, we have $f'(x)=6$. Therefore the answer would be $x=2$.

Hope that helps!

Comment: We are not solving for $x$.  We are solving for the value of $a$ such that $g'(a) = \dfrac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $g$ is the inverse of $f$, $g(f(y))=y$.  Taking the implicit derivative of both sides, it follows that $g'(f(y))f'(y)=1$.  Using the substitution $a=f(y)$ and $g'(a)=\frac{1}{6}$, you need $f'(y)=6$.

Comment: The answer is x=2, right? The book says the answer is x=5.. Edit: the book doesn't even have x=2 as an answer lol.

Comment: Look at what the question is asking for, it is asking for $x=a$.  I changed variables (to $y$) in my answer to try to be less confusing about this.